# How To Properly Use Dim

Tags: vba, excel

I am putting together a code in excel VBA.  I am no wiz, but have been learning for awhile now, but learning as i go.  I have searched the internet and have found much info on when to declare a variable, string or integer.  But I have yet to fully understand.  Using the code below i am successfully able to execute, without declaring any variables.  Question I have use should i be be using `Dim var1 to dim var100 or is this just not doing anything`

```
Var1 = frmdriverstep1.Labelpa54.Caption
Var2 = frmdriverstep1.Labelza54.Caption
Var3 = frmdriverstep1.ComboBoxga54.Text
Var4 = frmdriverstep1.ComboBoxna54.Text
Var5 = frmdriverstep1.a54label.Caption


DBFullName = "H:\*************.accdb"

Cs1 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";" & _
    "Persist Security Info=False;"

Set CnnConn = New ADODB.Connection
CnnConn.Open Cs1
'zone1
If Var1 >= "0" Then
Set Rst1 = New ADODB.Recordset
Rst1.Open "Zone1", CnnConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
Rst1.AddNew
Rst1.Fields("Audit_Date") = vardate
Rst1.Fields("Sequence") = varseq
Rst1.Fields("Style") = vartrim
Rst1.Fields("Auditor") = varauditor
Rst1.Fields("Catagory") = "WRINKLES"
Rst1.Fields("Portion") = Var1
Rst1.Fields("Zone") = Var2
Rst1.Fields("Grade") = Var3
Rst1.Fields("Number") = Var4
Rst1.Fields("Score") = Var5
Rst1.Fields("Seat_Model") = varmodel
Rst1.update
Rst1.Close
```

Comment: Use `option explicit` at the top of your file and try adding `dim` to your variables and you'll learn quickly if you're doing well or not. For example your var1 to var5, they're string. Write `dim var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 as string`

Comment: Using `Dim` will allow Excel to autocomplete and, the most important, try always to put `Dim` to all your `Set`

Comment: On older systems, it was imperative to **Dim**ension or '`Dim`' variables for the sake of memory management, as this told the compiler how much memory should be set aside to use for the scope of that variable (a `Boolean` wouldn't use as much as an `Integer` which wouldn't use as much as a `Long` for example). In modern day, this isn't as much of an issue, but without it there you **will** run into debugging errors and deprive yourself of IntelliSense which is a wonderful thing especially when you're learning.

Comment: @Hearner Using `dim var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 as string` only declares `var5` as `String` - the others are all `Variant`. You have to declare the type for each: `dim var1 As String, var2 As String, var3 As String, var4 As String, var5 as string`. Or use an array: `Dim avar(1 to 5) as String`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have `Option Explicit` specifically on the top of the module, you will not need to declare your variables in VBA, any undeclared variable will be considered a variable of type "Variant". However, this is a really poor coding habit, you should always declare your variable indicating their types.

Answer (score 10):

The real issue of not using `Option Explicit` is that you won't be informed of undeclared variable, and that may easily lead to debugging nightmares.
Consider the following code:

```
SomeUndeclaredVariable= 100
Debug.Print SomeUndeclareVariable
```

The second line will print a 0 without raising an error, and it might take a long time before you realize that the variable name used in the second line is different from the one in the first line.
Additionally, Variant are much less efficient than 'native' types.

Also, for Object variables, not declaring them properly deprives you from the benefit of Intellisense.
Note that there is an option in VBE to automatically insert that `Option Explicit` at the top of each new module.